# Сделать список в discord.py, в который можно добавлять свои элементы

Tags: бот, discord.py

Идея такова, нужно создать бота с помощью discord.py который будет создавать список игр, и для каждой игры нужно в отдельности выводить, кто в нее хочет сыграть. Я не очень понимаю как это обьяснить, поэтому просто покажу как это примерно будет выглядеть:
людей я буду обозначать Польз1, Польз2, Польз3 и т.д.

```
 Польз1: !list
 Бот: Список пуст!
 Польз1: !add Brawlhalla
 Бот: Brawlhalla добавлена в список!
 Польз2: !add The Forest
 Бот: The Forest добавлена в список!
 Польз2:!add Brawlhalla
 Бот: Brawlhalla добавлена в список!
 Польз3:!list
 Бот: Brawlhalla: Польз1, Польз2
      The Forest: Польз2
```

Прошу хотя бы примерно подсказать, как я это должен сделать. Пытался с помощью массивов, но не получилось. Буду рад любой помощи.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
game_list = {}

@bot.command(name='list')
async def print_list(context):
    if not game_list:
        await context.send('Список пуст!')
    else:
        for game, users in game_list.items():
            await context.send(f'{game}: {users}')


@bot.command(name='add')
async def add_game(context, game):
    users = ''
    if not game_list.get(game):
        game_list[game] = context.author.name
    else:
        users += str(game_list.get(game))
        users += f', {context.author.name}'
        game_list[game] = users
    await context.send(f'{game} добавлена')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@client.command()
async def add(ctx, game: str):
    global game1
    global game2
    game1 = []
    game2 = []
    if game == 'Brawlhalla':
        game1.append(ctx.message.author)
        await ctx.send('Brawlhalla добавлена в список!')
    if game == 'The Forest':
        game2.append(ctx.message.author)
        await ctx.send('The Forest добавлена в список!')

@client.command()
async def list(ctx):
    if game1 and game2 is None:
        await ctx.send('Список пуст!')
    else:#при умови если два массива не пустые
        for i in range(len(game1)):
            await ctx.send('Brawlhalla', game1[i])
        for i in range(len(game2)):
            await ctx.send('The Forest', game2[i])
```

Это самий простой и не оптимизированный способ!!!

Comment: Нет, немного не так. Нужно сделать так, что бы и игры можно было добавлять. Такой бы код я и сам написал, но нужно что бы не только пользователей можно было добавлять, но и сами игры.

Comment: Тогда добавьте еще одну переменную и используйте словарь